# What are some examples of interesting zoom slider customisations?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, ux

The [default Claro](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/map/map_topo.html) zoom slider control is pretty boring.

It's also hard to see on top of many basemaps:

[image]

Are there any examples of some nice customisations I could use for inspiration?

Comment: Minor nit pick...that's the out of the box claro slider. The slider is different depending on the dojo/dijit theme you're using (alternatives are tundra and nihilo).

Comment: Good point. Edited. Now, inspire me :)

Answer (score 2):

I like ArcGIS slider over other sliders from tech-giants. There is a lot you can do with dojo!

Check out [Ocean Charts from NOAA](http://ocs-gis.ncd.noaa.gov/encdirect/viewer.html). They use Flex, have nice transitions and have managed to pack most map navigation functions in one slider. I especially like the back button, something every map designer should consider! [image: Ocean Charts from NOAA]

If your app supports multiple base-maps (google, bing maps), and want to create a custom slider, you have [consistency issues](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2008/11/08/switching-between-mapping-apis-and-universal-map-levels/) to consider

[image]